# Colour change on text selection in a web page

Tags: html, css

How to change the colour of text when its selected by css/javascript? A cross browser compatible solution would be preferred.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @sp00m: may I point you to a meta question dealing with 'let me Google that for you' links: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15650/ban-lmgtfy-let-me-google-that-for-you-links

Comment: Ah, sorry, I didn't know... I just think he is the 1 000 000 th guy who wanna change the color of a selected text. But OK, I'll never do it again :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just use `::selection` in your stylesheet. you can view an example [on quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/selection.html). as you [can read here](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t315), this is supported by all modern browsers except internet explorer <9.